# Wordpress installation stuck at Choose a Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, installation, blogs, shared-hosting

I just recently installed the wordpress app via the Installatron on my godaddy hosted website. It led me to this configuration step with 4 steps. On the final step it requires me to select a theme. Although whenever I am doing so it seems to get hanged/stuck, also there is no continue or next button on the page to move further. Any ideas in this regards would be helpful.

[image]

Things I tried:

- Refresh the page - Brings me back to the same step in finishing the configuration with similar behavior.
- Tried to exit this configuration to create a new post, but brings it back to this same page.
- Similar behavior in both Chrome and Firefox.

Javascript console shows the following:

> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 
>   jquery-migrate.min.js:2:542

Comment: Check browser's console for JS errors?

Comment: oh ya did that, Let me update the response in my question

Comment: Have you tried other browser?

Comment: Yep tried both firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

you just skip this step and install the new theme using Apperence> theme option

Answer (score 0):

Skip past the Wizard to your dashboard.

Edit the url from:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/?page=wpem&step=theme
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/?page=wpem&step=start
```